# Configuring paper-ripple with "opacityDecayVelocity" attribute

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x, paper-elements

The default timing set by paper ripple animation 0.8s makes the transition seem slower.
Tried changing the value via :

```
<paper-ripple opacityDecayVelocity ="1.0"></paper-ripple>
```

Adding `$` as its an attribute

```
<paper-ripple opacityDecayVelocity$ ="1.0"></paper-ripple>
```

None seems to work. Please suggest a way to configure the attribute value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute name should be `opacity-decay-velocity`

```
<paper-ripple opacity-decay-velocity="1.0" ></paper-ripple>
```

See [Polymer Properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/properties)

> Attribute names with dashes are converted to camelCase property names
>   by capitalizing the character following each dash, then removing the
>   dashes. For example, the attribute first-name maps to firstName.
>   The same mappings happen in reverse when converting property names to attribute names